# Sorting by foreign key values in GridView with Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, gridview, sorting, foreign-keys

When using GridView's built in Sorting with Entity Framework, I can display foreign key values.  For example...

```
<asp:boundfield HeaderText="Category" DataField="Category.Name" SortExpression="Category.Name" />
```

...but when the header is clicked to sort the items in the grid, how can I sort my List list by Category.Name?

I only have the string "Category.Name", so I can't do this:

```
.OrderBy( e => e.Category.Name )
```

So I tried Reflection...

```
private static object GetPropertyValue( object obj, string propertyName )
{
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty( propertyName );
    return propertyInfo.GetValue( obj, null );
}

// list is List<Widget>
// with a breakpoint here, ((Widget)list[i]).Companies.Name exists in all Widgets
list.OrderBy( e => GetPropertyValue( e, "Category.Name" ) )
```

...which does not work.  No exception thrown, but doesn't sort by Category.Name.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I have been trying to figure this out for the last couple of days as i am moving an existing ASP.NET application from using SqlDataSources to EntityDataSources.  I found that you have to place an "it." in front of the statement.

So taking your example above you would need to form it like this:

```
<asp:boundfield HeaderText="Category" DataField="Category.Name" SortExpression="it.Category.Name" />
```

I have an Entity data source that looks like this:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource runat="server" ID="edsResourceRoles"  ConnectionString="name=SkillsEntities"
    DefaultContainerName="SkillsEntities" EnableUpdate="true" EnableDelete="true"
    EnableInsert="true" EntitySetName="ResourceRoles" Where="it.resource_id = @resource_id"
    Include="Roles,Competency_Level" OrderBy="it.Roles.roles_nm">
```

and then i can control the sorting of the Roles Name column by using the SortExpression="it.Roles.roles_nm".

Hope this helps someone else out there who is looking for an answer.

Comment: How did you find this? Is this documented *anywhere*? I realize this answer is almost 4 years old, but it would be nice if anyone could shed some light on this, since I expected this not to work, but it actually did.